# Populating a drop down box using javascript from server side files

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a small site that has a dropdown box which I hope I can populate from a folder on a hosted server, each item in the dropdown box should represent the file name of each file in the folder.

This is then linked to a button which will call a function load selected data into a script to visualize.

I am currently unsure about loading the file list into the application.

so far I have:

drop down list (note: using jade):

```
select#dataSetChoice
```

the function to run a script based on the contents of the drop down box:

```
    function loadDataSet(){
      var dataSet = dataSetChoice.options[dataSetChoice.selectedIndex].text;
      initialize(dataSet);
    }
```

the button event:

```
  button(onclick='loadDataSet()') Load data
```

all I need to do down is populate the drop box list based on the contents of this folder:

```
http://localhost/data/
```

Edit: html directory listing as requested

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index of /pje40</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Index of /pje40</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">
                <img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]">
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5"><hr></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/">Parent Directory</a>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">  - </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="week1">week1</a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                2013-12-06 19:28
            </td>
            <td align="right">119K</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="week2">week2</a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                2013-12-06 19:28
            </td>
            <td align="right">119K</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="week3">week3</a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                2013-12-06 19:28
            </td>
            <td align="right">119K</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="5"><hr></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Should the jquery look similar to this:

script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')

```
var returned_html = $.trim($('http://localhost/pje40/').html());

var trs = $(returned_html).find('tr');
trs.splice(0, 2);
trs.splice(trs.length - 1, 1);

var directory_list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
{
    var tds = $(trs[i]).find('td');
    directory_list.push({
        "icon": $(tds[0]).find('img').attr('src'),
        "name": $(tds[1]).find('a').html(),
        "href": $(tds[1]).find('a').attr('href'),
        "last_modified": $(tds[2]).html(),
        "size": $(tds[3]).html(),
        "description": $(tds[4]).html()
    });
}

alert(directory_list.length);
```

Comment: What about your server side? Have you tried to get the directory listing and send it to the client with JSON? Or you have enabled directory listing on your web server and want to parse it with JS?

Comment: Ideally running this on client side i think?
And directory listing is enabled on the server

Comment: Can't say I like notion of parsing HTML is JS. Not that it's very hard  but rather could be not so stable, eg. HTML of directory listing could  change with web server upgrade. But if it's the way you want it, please, show example HTML of directory listing so we can help you.

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Are you using jQuery alongside with Ember?

Comment: Not currently, but I can be?
Currently using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the sketch of what can be done with your problem. I have used jQuery to somehow ease DOM traversion

```
// Lets say `returned_html` it what came from server
var returned_html = $.trim($('#returned_html').html());

// We need to find all TRs and drop first two and the last one
var trs = $(returned_html).find('tr');
trs.splice(0, 2);
trs.splice(trs.length - 1, 1);

// Now we should have 4 lines (with to Parent Directory one).
// Lets create list
var directory_list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
{
    var tds = $(trs[i]).find('td');
    directory_list.push({
        "icon": $(tds[0]).find('img').attr('src'),
        "name": $(tds[1]).find('a').html(),
        "href": $(tds[1]).find('a').attr('href'),
        "last_modified": $(tds[2]).html(),
        "size": $(tds[3]).html(),
        "description": $(tds[4]).html()
    });
}
```

You'll get in `directory_list`:

```
[
    {
        description: "&nbsp;",
        href: "/",
        icon: "/icons/back.gif",
        last_modified: "&nbsp;",
        name: "Parent Directory",
        size: "  - "
    },
    {
        description: "&nbsp;",
        href: "week1",
        icon: "/icons/unknown.gif",
        last_modified: "↵                2013-12-06 19:28↵            ",
        name: "week1",
        size: "119K"
    },
    {
        description: "&nbsp;",
        href: "week2",
        icon: "/icons/unknown.gif",
        last_modified: "↵                2013-12-06 19:28↵            ",
        name: "week2",
        size: "119K"
    },
    {
        description: "&nbsp;",
        href: "week3",
        icon: "/icons/unknown.gif",
        last_modified: "↵                2013-12-06 19:28↵            ",
        name: "week3",
        size: "119K"
    }
]
```

As you can see it still needs some post processing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r8Vp/) to play with.

**Update**

You can get directory listing with

```
$.get('http://localhost/pje40/', function(html) {
    process_listing(html);
});
```

You should proccess returned data in callback because `$.get()` is async by default.

But you can run into cross domain request problem here. Please read about [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The other way would be to create hidden `iframe` and load `http://localhost/pje40/`. Then do some thing like I've done in my first fiddle.

Needless to say that `process_listing()` in this case is

```
function process_listing(returned_html)
{
    // We need to find all TRs and drop first two and the last one
    var trs = $(returned_html).find('tr');
    trs.splice(0, 2);
    trs.splice(trs.length - 1, 1);

    // Now we should have 4 lines (with to Parent Directory one).
    // Lets create list
    var directory_list = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
    {
        var tds = $(trs[i]).find('td');
        directory_list.push({
            "icon": $(tds[0]).find('img').attr('src'),
            "name": $(tds[1]).find('a').html(),
            "href": $(tds[1]).find('a').attr('href'),
            "last_modified": $(tds[2]).html(),
            "size": $(tds[3]).html(),
            "description": $(tds[4]).html()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated initial question